# wp-plugin or any code for password protection for particular categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

1. I want to apply password protection to my particular category and in
   one forum,i saw this code.But,it wont worked for me.
2. Included this code in my theme's function.php:

   `global $post;

       if ( ! is_single() ) return false;

       // edit these
       $password = 'your password';
       $protected_categories = array('category-slug-name');
       // stop editing

       if ( in_category( $protected_categories, $post->ID ) && stripslashes( $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] ) != $password )
       {
           $post->post_content = get_the_password_form();
       }

   }`


   }
   ?>
3. Any ideas regarding this.Its bit urgent for me.if any ideas you have please reply to my question.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:
http://codecanyon.net/item/privatecontent-multilevel-content-plugin/1467885?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=LCweb

Answer (score 0):

I hardcoded my category page for password protection-

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
//create a table named pass_protect_cat with password field in it.
$db_pass = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT password FROM pass_protect_cat",ARRAY_N); 
$db_pass1=array_shift( $db_pass );
$db_password=array_shift($db_pass1);
$cat_pass_entered=$_POST['pass'];
$displayform=true;
if ($_POST['submitted'] )
{
    if((strcmp($db_password,$cat_pass_entered)) == 0)
    {
        $displayform=false;
    ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <p align="left" class="txt_small"><?php the_content().'<br/>'; ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<b>'."Wrong Password".'</b>';
    }
}
if($displayform)
{
```

?>

```
<p align="left" class="txt_small" id="Message">These category posts are Password Protected.<br/>Enter the password to view the contents.</p>
                <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php password_protect_cat.php ?>" >
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="">
                    <input type="submit" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="Submit">
                </form>

<?php } ?>
```